# Placemark not all displaying using google map api

Tags: google-maps

First time asking a question so sorry if it's not well worded. I'm trying to display a placemark over every country with a custom icon for each (their flag), using a KML file. If i look at the file using google earth everything works fine but when its loaded on google map it only displays a small number of them (around 20). Does anyone know if there is a limit for custom icons on placemark? https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/mapsSupport according to this i don't think so but im kinda lost.

All the links to the png imgs works.

Comment: What does your KML look like?  Have you tried a KMZ file?  Possibly related [issue](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=3864), from this possibly related question: [Custom icons in KML occasionally break in Google Maps](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9525552/custom-icons-in-kml-occasionally-break-in-google-maps)